# How can I get the total count for a single column in a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Test table has been country column it has been multiple values.

Sample

```
 USA,ENGLAND,SPAIN === This 3 Count mean
```

or

```
TURKEY,ITALY === this 2 count mean
```

or

```
17,288,9,15 = this 4 count mean
```

so what can ı do in controller for this get count ?

Comment: Okay, okay, calm down, don't yell at us. In other words - please edit the title and remove all caps.

Comment: There is a `Count` extension method in LINQ you can use. ex : `someCollection.Count()`

Comment: If you have it in memory then: `"17,288,9,15".Split(',').Count()`  If you are running N Rows Query maybe you should do this using SQL.

Comment: please can I take a little detailed sample I need to test it in the action controls could you make a fully example multiple values with a single field and I need to show them primarily in the action controller and I need to reflect them on the action via datatable (view)